# Recommend a wireless PCI card for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, hardware-rec, pci

I have a crummy RT2500-based 11g card which does work in Windows 7 with the Vista driver (3.2.0.0) but it dies about every two hours or so.  Googling around has led me to conclude that Ralink drivers are basically borked, and that I need something else for a stable connection.

Can anyone recommend a suitable wireless adapter?  It needs to be:

1. 802.11g - draft-N nice but not at all essential.
2. PCI - I already have far more USB devices than can possibly be good for me.
3. Very reliable.

Money isn't an object within reason.

Answer (score 1):

For a budget, this one has great reviews: [link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833180052)

If you want more of a name brand, Linksys is my choice: [link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124351)

If you have a PCI-Express x1 port, I'd highly recommend using it, so you save your PCI slots for other things: [link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833127218)

The first one and the third one have great reviews.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'll look into these and report back.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft 64bit Wireless Adapter Compatability Site](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Browse.aspx?type=Hardware&category=Networking&subcategory=Wireless%20Network%20Cards)

Answer (score 0):

i'm using a couple of Linksys WLAN-WMP300N, they're not the cheapest though ($70+) but quality stuff.

[image]

Comment: thats awesome but U.G.L.Y.  lol

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a PCI wireless adapter for my Windows 7 x64 machine and it worked right out of the box (drivers were built into Windows):

[TRENDnet TEW-423PI PCI Wireless Adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156141&Tpk=TEW-423PI).

It's inexpensive ($20) and guaranteed to work in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

My WMP300N works perfectly with Windows 7. I use it to connect to the internet rather than run a new cable connection. It was all in place with Windows XP, then Vista, and recently upgraded to Windows 7.

Comment: whoever is suggesting the WMP300N for Windows 7 64-bit is mistaken. There is NO support for the 64 bit version of Windows 7 for this card and the manufacturer will point you to the WMP600N. I screwed myself by trying to update Windows with this card installed. Just search for WMP300N Windows 7 and see the nightmare others have had.